# passing in a le or ge sign in python

Tags: python, mysql

I hope this has not been asked previously, I was not sure what keywords to use.

Suppose I want to write a function that can take a less than or equal to statement for a query...

```
import MySQLdb

def query1(date,le):
  '''
  query1('2013-01',<= )
  >>> 10
  '''

  query = '''
  select * 
  from   table 
  where  number {x} 1
         and date = {dt}
  '''.format(dt=date,x=le)

  cursor.execute(query)
  rslt = cursor.fetchall()

  return rslt
```

Then what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your date call might fail. `DATE` also stores the `DAY` and you are missing it in passed string.

Comment: Thanks... i have stripped the time-stamp in the original.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the comparison operator as a string to your function:

```
query1('2013-01', '<=')
```

This will insert the string for the operator in to the query, resulting in

```
select * 
from   table 
where  number <= 1
     and date = 2013-01
```

Please note that directly building SQL queries by inserting strings is a potential vector for SQL injections. If you allow users to supply their own date  strings, the user could inject some SQL code in and run malicious code. Look in to query parameterisation for more information.

If you wanted to guard against SQL injection, you should do something like the following. The allowed operators list is carefully whitelisted, so only valid and safe operators can be used. This is used to build the query. The date is then injected in to the query by the `cursor.execute()` command. `MySQLdb` then handles constructing a safe query from your data, and will not allow a malicious user to inject their own SQL in place of the date string.

```
import MySQLdb

def query1(date, comp):
    query = '''
    select * 
    from   table 
    where  number {comp} 1
           and date = %s
    '''.format(comp=sql_comp_operator(comp))

    cursor.execute(query, (date, ))
    return cursor.fetchall()

def sql_comp_operator(comp):
     operators = {
         'lt': '<',
         'lte': '<',
         'gt': '>',
         'gte': '>=',
     }
     if comp in operators:
         return operators[comp]
     else:
         raise ValueError("Unknown comparison operator '{}'".format(comp))

query1('2013-01', 'lte')
```

Comment: ...thanks! i had thought about the sql injection. this was just something run by me at the moment. But I will read more about the query  parameterisation. Thank you for the help

Comment: o thanks a lot! the dictionary is a great idea, i was about to use case.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd want to use an ORM to prevent SQL injection attacks (I prefer [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)/[Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki)) which would let you do stuff like:

```
q = session.query(User).\
    filter(User.id <= 1).\
    filter(User.date_of_birth == date)
```

Sounds like you want "le" to be a function/lambda that you can pass in, but I don't know of any way to convert that lambda to a string for putting in your query. For example, you could call it like:

```
query1('2013-01-01', lambda x,y: x <= y)
```

But there's no real way I know of to convert that in your query to "<=". If you pass it in as a string, however, you can used format with named blocks, by passing in a dictionary with keys with the same names as those blocks, like this:

```
sql = """
select * 
  from   table 
  where  number {operation} 1
         and date = '{date}'
"""

data = {
    "operation": "<=",
    "date": "2013-01-01"
}

query = sql.format(**data)
```